# Navigation View Item Action Error

Tags: android, class, menu

I want to use an Array for Menu items in Navigation View. I create my menu on the left side. But when i click the item i want to show name of item. But it makes an error. I tried this using another variable. (For example i determine an variable instead of "i" like (int counter)" But it gave an error like before.)

[image]

thank for your help.thank you.

```
/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.technotalkative.navigationviewdemo, PID: 28374
              java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=4; index=4
                  at com.technotalkative.navigationviewdemo.MainActivity$3.onMenuItemClick(MainActivity.java:290)
                  at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:148)
                  at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:957)
                  at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter$1.onClick(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:318)
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)


    private int counter=0;
private void addItemsRunTime(NavigationView navigationView) {
    //adding items run time
    final Menu menu = navigationView.getMenu();
    for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
        counter=i;
        menu.add(0,i,0,i + bilgiler[i].toString());
        menu.findItem(i).setIcon(R.drawable.coins);
        menu.findItem(i).setCheckable(true); //Bu kod seçili kısmı tek bir seçenekli hale getiriyor.
        menu.findItem(i).setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Selam Tıkladığınız Butonun Adı" + bilgiler[counter].toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                counter++;
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
    final SubMenu subMenu = menu.addSubMenu("SubMenu Title");
    for (int i = 0; i < sayacim; i++) {
        subMenu.add(0,i,0,bilgiler[i].toString());
        subMenu.findItem(i).setIcon(R.drawable.resmim2);
    }

    for (int i = 0, count = mNavigationView.getChildCount(); i < count; i++) {
        final View child = mNavigationView.getChildAt(i);
        if (child != null && child instanceof ListView) {
            final ListView menuView = (ListView) child;
            final HeaderViewListAdapter adapter = (HeaderViewListAdapter) menuView.getAdapter();
            final BaseAdapter wrapped = (BaseAdapter) adapter.getWrappedAdapter();
            wrapped.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Array codes here

```
public static String[] bilgiler;
        stringArray = parseJson(result);
        sayaca=(Integer)stringArray.length;
        tvData2.setText("Burası arrayden geliyor :" + stringArray[1].toString() + sayaca );
        sayacim = sayaca;
        bilgiler = new String[sayacim];
        bilgiler = stringArray;
        setupToolbar();
        initNavigationDrawer();
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that you are trying to access variable from inner class. Solution: declare your variable before that method -

```
public Integer i;
private void addItemsRunTime(...){
...
for (i = 0; ....){
}

}
```

EDITED:

in your toast instead of biligiler[i].toString() write item.getTitle().toString() or read about MenuItem: developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MenuItem.html

Comment: i tried this. It works and after i click the item my application has crashed, stopped. /AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.technotalkative.navigationviewdemo, PID: 19304
                  java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=4; index=4
                      at com.technotalkative.navigationviewdemo.MainActivity$3.onMenuItemClick(MainActivity.java:285)

Comment: in your toast instead of biligiler[i].toString() write item.getTitle().toString()

or read about MenuItem: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MenuItem.html

Comment: thank you so much Tomas Pavlovic. I solve the problem with your solution. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
private int counter = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
    //in interface
    ....bilgiger[counter]

   //at the end
   counter++;
}
```

Comment: it shows allways last array string. i click first item it shows last items title. i click second item it shows last items title. it does not work.

Comment: i click the item it chrashes it stops.does not work.

Comment: i add log cat to my first message.

Comment: please post your bilgiger[] array initialization

Comment: i post it my first message

Comment: I still don't know what is bilgiger array, you need to have something like this in your code : private Object bilgiger[] = new Object[x];